# In a Generic Provider how to find and edit properties of T? (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics

So, I'm making a generic provider for my repositories implementation which will be used by my BaseController (ASP.NET MVC 2) for low-level objects. These objects have common operations, such as Activate/Deactivate/Delete/Edit, so I'll always be working with the same property on each. The problem is, since I don't know what T is, I obviously don't have access to its properties.

So, my question is, can someone show me how to get the properties I need out of the objects. I've seen some people talking about Reflection, others Expression Trees, neither of which I know how to use.

I do have a generic repository which I believe uses Expression Trees (copied it from some website), but again, I don't know what I'm doing with it... If it helps, here's what I've got so far:

```
public class Provider<T> where T : class {
    private readonly Repository<T> Repository = null;

    public Provider(
        Repository<T> Repository) {
        this.Repository = Repository;
    }

    public void Activate(
        int Id) {
        T Entity = this.Repository.Select(Id);

        // Need to get the property here, change it and move on...

        this.Repository.Submit();
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Do the 'low-level objects' inherit from a common interface or base class? If so, you can restrict `T` to that; `where T : IInterface`.

Comment: They don't. They're all Linq to Sql classes by them selves...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If those classes have common operations, sounds like they should inherit from the same base or implement the same interface, correct? If so, use that interface/base as the constraint for T

```
public class Provider<T> where T : ICommonInterface
```

You will then have compile-time access to the shared members provided by the interface or base class.

Comment: It would work, but they don't inherit from a base class. They're all Linq to Sql objects.

Comment: @Alex, Don't know much about Linq-to-SQL. But the generated classes are partial, correct? Which means at worst, you can create other partials for those classes and indicate the common interface there. I don't know, you might be able to make that part of the data model outright. It's a thought worth exploring.

Comment: Anthony is 100% correct - we've followed this pattern before, and implemented the 'other side' of the partial classes to add additional behavior/implement interfaces/inherit from base classes.  When you re-generate the DBML, it only updates its own .cs files, not your .cs files that provide the other half of the partial.

Comment: @Anthony, you're right, it does actually work. Alas, I found a design flaw with my system when I was done which forces me not to use this implementation. The "low-level" objects are something like `Address` and are linked to other objects `EmployeeAddress`, `ContactAddress`, etc. Well, problem is once any of the methods on the Provider are done, I don't know to where to go back to (in terms of routes), so I'll have to add the logic to individual providers, such as the `EmployeeProvider`. Too bad, if this would have worked, I would have saved a tonne of code... Oh, well...

Comment: @Michael, I'm pretty much done implementing it, but the compiler is yelling at me because I can't have fields in the interface. How did you get around this? That's the only error stopping the compiler and I'd like to get past it to see if all the typing since last night will pay off...

Comment: I didn't get around this.  We used properties/methods in the interface, and fields in the base class if needed: `public partial class Car : Entity, ICar`.  Entity was an abstract class that contains common stuff, ICar was an interface which was used primarily to define the fields that would be generated out of the database.  The interface was passed around the application allowing for injection and mocking.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution will be to give the objects a common base type, and constrain the type parameter T to be of that type. Then you'll have access to the methods or properties of the common base type at compile time:

```
public class Provider<T> where T : ICommon 
{ 
    ...
}
```

or

```
public class Provider<T> where T : CommonBase
{
    ...
}
```

If that's not possible, then without a common base type the best you can do is reflect upon the objects to look for and invoke the property that you are interested in:

```
public void Activate(int Id) 
{ 
    T entity = this.Repository.Select(Id); 

    // Interrogate the type of the entity and get the property called "MyPropertyName"
    PropertyInfo pi = entity.GetType().GetProperty("MyPropertyName"); 

    // Invoke the property against the entity instance - this retrieves the 
    // value of the property.
    var value = (YourType)(pi.GetValue(entity, null));

    // Do somethign with the value...        

    this.Repository.Submit(); 
}
```

I should add that reflection is comparatively expensive and you also lose the compile time verification. But it's handy in cases like these.

You can get a MethodInfo object for working with methods by calling:

```
MethodInfo mi = entity.GetType().GetMethod("MyMethodName");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make an action

```
public void Activate(int Id, Action<T> doSomething)
{
    T Entity = this._repository.Select(Id);
    // Need to get the property here, change it and move on... 
    doSomething(Entity);
    _repository.Submit();
}
```

Then using the Action delegate (in this example via a lambda) the properties will be known when activate is called:

```
prov.Activate(5, x => x.Address = "fgfgf");
```